# get the value from checked box in excel using Apache POI

Tags: apache, apache-poi, excel-2010

[image: check box]

I have these options (image link above) in my excel sheet in cells, E19, 20 and 21. How do I get the value of the box that is checked using Apache POI. I tried `getBooleanValue();` , but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `getBooleanCellValue()` on the cell.

Here's a basic example, assuming the cell is A1 :

```
FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream("test.xlsx");
XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream);
XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
XSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(0);
XSSFCell cell = row.getCell(0);

cell.getBooleanCellValue();
```

Comment: getBooleanCellValue() doesn't seem to work. The cellType() for the check box cell returns cell type BLANK. Looks like, the xml formats should be read to see if the check box is checked and to get the value. But I quite don't know how to do it. But getBooleanCellValue() is not working.

Comment: Solved. Unzipped the Excel and parsed the Xml file and it worked. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Can you explain how to did it? i don't get that point of unzipping excel file.